# SQL selecting from two tables returns duplicate values - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have to retrieve some all data from two tables. There is no condition. But my code returns duplicated values of data. 
each table contain 4 rows

Centres tbl:

[image: centres_tbl]

Training Course tbl:

[image: tbl_training_course]

Output:

[image: View output Screenshot]

My Controller code:

```
    $this->load->model("admindata"); 
    $data ['query'] = $this->admindata->getcentrelist(); 

    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->view('admin/header');
    $this->load->view('admin/training',$data);
    $this->load->view('admin/footer');
```

My query on Model is:

```
public function getcentrelist()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $query=  $this->db->query('SELECT centre_name,course_name from tbl_training_courses, tbl_traning_centres'); 
    return $query->result();
}
```

View: (training.php)

```
<?php foreach($query as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row->centre_name; ?></td>             
        </tr>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Add a join condition based on key columns in the two tables

Comment: provide your db structure and we could help rewriting the query

Comment: ok.. i can add its screenshots

Comment: You have not mentioned relation between two tables, you can use query as SELECT tbl_traning_centres.centre_name,tbl_training_courses.course_name from tbl_training_courses, tbl_traning_centres

Comment: There is no relation for this purpose.. I need to show all the values.. (List of courses and centres in a same page).... Thanks for your reply

Comment: SELECT tbl_training_courses.course_name, tbl_traning_centres.centre_name from tbl_training_courses, tbl_traning_centres -- Same problem :(

Comment: Every centre is being related to every course. If you were to change your `foreach` code to `<tr><td><?php echo $row->centre_name . ' - ' . $row->course_name; ?></td></tr>` You'd see that there are no duplicates. What are you trying to display in training.php exactly?

Comment: try adding `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: i would've ran 2 queries separately as there is no relation between both tables.

Answer (score 2):

This is normal because of the implicit join you made! Why don't you simply request two queries, one per table, and then merge the results in one array?

```
public function getcentrelist()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $query_courses=  $this->db->query('SELECT course_name as name from tbl_training_courses');  
    $query_centers=  $this->db->query('SELECT centre_name as name from tbl_traning_centres'); 
    $courses = $query_courses->result();
    $centers = $query_centers->result();
    return array_merge($courses,$centers);
}
```

Note please that I have renamed the fields course_name and center name to a unified name: "name", this is necessary to have a coherent merged table.

Comment: This is how you should do it, except not select centre_name and course_name in both queries.

Comment: Thank you for the note, But as the structure is different in the two tables, aliases are necessary then. I will fix it in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`DISTINCT`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)**

```
public function getcentrelist()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $query=  $this->db->query('SELECT DISTINCT centre_name,course_name from tbl_training_courses, tbl_traning_centres GROUP BY center_name'); 
    return $query->result();
}
```

or use **[`Group By`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)**

```
public function getcentrelist()
{
    $this->load->database();
    $query=  $this->db->query('SELECT centre_name,course_name from tbl_training_courses, tbl_traning_centres GROUP BY center_name'); 
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The data returns by your query is normal because you select One line and you fetch all lines of the second table so if you have 10 lines in the second line you will get each value 10 times and if you even put distinct you will get a problem. To avoid such a problem you need to use condition or Join between two tables.