# Redirecting to another page after logging in Using CodeIgniter framework

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I created a Login controller and when I redirect to the home page of my site, it won't redirect to my view which is the index.

Here is my controller (main.php):

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
     {
       parent::__construct();
     }

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('login');
}

public function validate_credentials () {

            $this->load->model("membership_model");
            $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

            if($query){
                $data = array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'is_logged_in' => true
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect('Main/homepage1', 'refresh');
            }
            else {
                $this->index();
            }
        }

    public function homepage1 () {
        $this->load->view("index");
    }


  }
```

here is my form inside login_view.php

```
<form class="form-login" method="post" name="redirect" action="<?php echo site_url("Main/validate_credentials"); ?>">
            <h2 class="form-login-heading">sign in now</h2>
            <div class="login-wrap">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" autofocus value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" >
                <br>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  value = "<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <a data-toggle="modal" href="login.php#myModal"> Forgot Password?</a>

                    </span>
                </label>
                <button class="btn btn-theme btn-block" name="login" href="index.html" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> SIGN IN</button>
             </div>

             <?php  $this->load->view("modals/forgot_pass_modal"); ?>

          </form>
```

and my model:

```
<?php if( ! defined ('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');

class Membership_model extends CI_Model{

    public function __construct()
     {
       parent::__construct();
     }

    public function validate () {
        $this->db->where('admin_username', $this->input->post('username'));
        $this->db->where("admin_pword", md5($this->input->post("password")));
        $query = $this->db->get("administration");

        if($query->num_rows() == 1){
            return true;
        }
    }


}
 ?>
```

Can someone help me? Because It is my first time using this PHP framework and I really appreciate if you could help me out.

Comment: can you show us routes.php entry of your redirect('Main/homepage1'); ? It will help anyone to understand.

Comment: here: $route['default_controller'] = "Main";
$route['404_override'] = '';

Comment: where is the route for Main/homepage1 ?

Comment: in the version I am currently using right now, there are only two variables inside route.php. I am using 2.1.4

Comment: try this, `redirect('main/homepage1');`

Comment: You have to define the route there i.e $route['routename'] = 'controller_name/method_name'; in your case $route['Main/homepage1'] = 'Main/homepage1';

Comment: I tried and it is still not working..

Comment: krish, okay i'll try this.

Comment: still not working....

Comment: are the credentials you are passing correct for login??

Comment: in your form action use base_url('main/validate_credentials') also do not use MD5 for passwords another good thing is codeigniter http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html and http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**In View**

```
<input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" autofocus value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" >
<br>
<input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  value = "<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>">
```

**In Controller**

```
public function validate_credentials () {

    $this->load->model("membership_model");
    $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

    if($query == 1){
        $data = array(
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'is_logged_in' => true
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('Main/homepage1');
    }
    else {
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

**In Model**

```
public function validate () {
    $this->db->where('admin_username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where("admin_pword", md5($this->input->post("password")));
    $query = $this->db->get("administration");
    $result = $query->result_array();
    $count = count($result);

    return $count;

}
```

Comment: For the question, main thing was the issue with name from textboxes. But your answer didnt had this issue pointed. How come after 23minutes that part is added??

Comment: @NiranjanNRaju i have Added it already.  At that time our office server has down. so by that fixing time its get so late

Comment: Only the view part is added... Only for that block server was down??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33863044/sql-selecting-from-two-tables-returns-duplicate-values-codeigniter/33864166#33864166

Comment: answered 54 minutes ago. means after answering, you were active.

Answer (score 1):

you have missed name attributes in form.

```
<input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" autofocus value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" >
       ^             ^
<input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  value = "<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>">
       ^             ^
```

Without specifying the name, you are trying to access in model

By changing your code should work. I thibk rest everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have forgot to add form `attributes` on `login_view.php`

Replace your `view code` with this...

```
<form class="form-login" method="post" name="redirect" action="<?php echo site_url("main/validate_credentials"); ?>">
        <h2 class="form-login-heading">sign in now</h2>
        <div class="login-wrap">
            <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="User ID" autofocus value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>" >
            <br>
            <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"  value = "<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>">
            <label class="checkbox">
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <a data-toggle="modal" href="login.php#myModal"> Forgot Password?</a>

                </span>
            </label>
            <button class="btn btn-theme btn-block" name="login" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> SIGN IN</button>
         </div>

         <?php  $this->load->view("modals/forgot_pass_modal"); ?>

 </form>
```

And replace **Model** with this

```
 <?php if( ! defined ('BASEPATH')) exit ('No direct script access allowed');

            class Membership_model extends CI_Model{

                public function __construct()
                 {
                   parent::__construct();
                 }

                public function validate () {

                    $this->db->select('admin_username');
                    $this->db->where('admin_username', $this->input->post('username'));
                    $this->db->where("admin_pword", md5($this->input->post("password")));
                    $query = $this->db->get("administration");

                    return $query->row();
                }


            }
        ?>
```

In **Controller**

Replace `validate_credentials` method with this code

```
 public function validate_credentials () {

            $this->load->model("membership_model");
            $query = $this->membership_model->validate();

            if($query->admin_username){
                $data = array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'is_logged_in' => true
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                redirect(base_url().'main/homepage1');
            }
            else {
                $this->index();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

as your issue is just about redirection please follow as below

```
redirect('Main/homepage1', 'refresh');
```

as

```
$url = site_url('main/homepage1');
 redirect($url);
```

you did not need to give it refresh when you are redirecting to new link.
hope it helps